# Advice on using sandbox vs. caching for UITableView async image download

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage, sandbox

Apple just released some sample code on lazy loading images in a UITableView a week ago. I checked it out and implemented it into my own UITableView (which is a drawRect one for fast scrolling), to see if there was a difference from what I was already doing.

After implementing I am not sure what is best; the new code or what I already had. I am not seeing much of a speed improvement on my 3GS.

"Sandbox" method: Load images lazily, then save to local tmp folder in the sandbox. *Each time* the cell is displayed it looks for whether an image with that filename is already located in the sandbox folder. If it is, it retrieves the image and displays it, if not it continues with the download, saves it locally and then displays it. The benefit with this is that the images won't be blank the second time you open the app. They will already be downloaded and ready for displaying.

Caching method: This also loads the images lazily, however, now I include a UIImage on each object in the array that's displayed in the tableview. Instead of saving the image locally, I now download the image and put it into the array for the object. Now, instead of checking for the filename every single time, it jut check whether the UIImage != nil and uses the cached image (or downloads if nil).

A small difference is also that the caching code resizes the image before caching it to the exact size of what is displayed in the cell, whereas the image used in the sandbox code example is actually a bit larger than what it needs to display, which means it has to resize on the fly when scrolling as well. I read months ago that this could be a bit expensive to do, and I am also not sure whether it makes much of a difference in terms of then using a cached image instead of the sandbox-stored image and therefore more CPU intensive anyway (compared to what you save from caching with the caching code above).

I guess my question would be whether I should even bother with the caching code? Again, the new code won't immediately load images on a new launch, whereas the old code actually does because it's already in the sandbox. Since I am not reusing images, I have a lot of images to load (from the sandbox or cache) so I am not noticing a huge difference in speed. In fact, on my 3GS it's almost impossible to tell, in my opinion. The scrolling is not silky smooth, and I assume this is due to the large amount of images that I cannot reuse (different image for each cell). I am also wondering whether the sandbox method would get slower once there's 1000+ images in the folder, for example, eventually having it look through many more images than just 100 or so.

I hope I am making sense. I wanted to be pretty thorough with the details, and I am happy to give more details if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone reading this now (since it's an old post) I would highly recommend checking out the built in image caching in AFNetworking or the great UIImageView/UIImage extension SDWebImage which both handle caching and async downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only good way to tell if there is any discernible difference in performance is to use profiling tools like Instruments (for measuring things like display framerate for the two techniques) or Shark (to determine hotspots in your code). There could be small differences in your exact implementation that could potentially cause significant differences between any general answer we could give and the actual performance you see in your application.

The thing that primarily concerns me with the "sandbox" method is not performance but disk space usage. Users won't appreciate you filling up their iPhone or iPod Touch with unnecessary files, especially if all the images aren't consistently used or if the set of used images changes often. Without knowing more about your application its impossible to guess how often these cached images would be loaded.

If you're testing locally on your own device, you might be on Wifi network. My recommendation would be to turn Wifi off for part of your testing to see how the two approaches perform when you have to fetch all the images over the cellular network. I would also recommend trying to find an older device (iPhone 3G or worse) because the 3GS does in fact hide potential performance issues that could be annoying for users on older devices.

I have personally used the LazyTableImages technique in my apps many times (provided it hasn't changed drastically between WWDC09 and the recent 'release') and find it to be just what I need. Caching images on disk wouldn't be an option in my case, however, and you shouldn't take my anecdote too strongly into account - profile your own code and use the results it shows.

#### Edit:

The obvious answer is that accessing an in-memory cache is going to be faster than accessing the filesystem, but of course the final word on that is left up to profiling. If the images are already in memory, they don't need to be read from flash and parsed by UIImage. The traditional tradeoff comes into play here though - in-memory caching vs. disk space.

While it may be faster for you to store your images in-memory, you need to be very sure that you correctly handle memory warnings in your application (as you should be doing anyway!). Otherwise long period of use will lead to many, many images in your in-memory cache and trigger memory warnings and if your application is not built to handle these, at best your application will be killed by the OS due to lack of memory resources.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Re. the sandbox, it's in the tmp folder, so it does not get backed up. I have also set the limit to 10MB and clean it out if the sandbox size reaches 10MB+.

I use the same method for downloading the images lazily, basically, so I am not too concerned about whether one is faster for the actual downloading of the images. I am more interested in seeing which of the two is faster in terms of performance (caching vs. sandboxing).

Answer (score 1):

If you have code that already works, and there's not a pressing problem, then don't change it.

If your scrolling actually *is* too slow, then perhaps you could use a mixture of ideas, and try to get the UIImage, and if it's not there, load it from the sandbox, and if it's not there, then download it.

Comment: I am already doing the "download if not there, then save, then load from sandbox" approach. It's just in terms of "sandboxing" the image and retrieving it that way or putting it into the object's uiimage object.

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons in both approaches that you present - I suggest using elements of both in your app.

It's better to keep your images in memory and save them later (perhaps when your app quits). If you have a lot of images, it might be faster to use Core Data to save them, than as regular files.

It's also better to avoid doing any resizing on the fly, i.e. in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: methods or in any method that has to do with drawing your cells' content view. If you can, ask the image provider (content management?) to supply images at the size that your table view displays.